# TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function - Firebase error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Ive implemented stripe into firebase and everytime a user upgrades their plan this line of code is supposed to run, but it throws . It is supposed to create a checkoutsessions in the users collection. I've tried everything and even asked chatGPT what could be wrong. Im not sure its an issue in my firebase because everything seems well set up.

```
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import initializeStripe from "./initializeStripe";

export async function createMonthlyCheckout(uid) {
  let checkoutSessionRef;

  try {
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    checkoutSessionRef = await addDoc(
      collection(doc(firestore, "users", uid), "checkout_sessions"),
      {
        price: "price_1ODfHmDueGWaYjB35b45Vl1B",
        success_url: window.location.origin + "/settings",
        cancel_url: window.location.origin + "/for-you",
      }
    );

    console.log("Document added with ID: ", checkoutSessionRef.id);

    onSnapshot(checkoutSessionRef, (snap) => {
      const { sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (sessionId) {
        initializeStripe().then((stripe) => {
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  }
}
```

I tried adding a try and catch to figure out the issue but I dont know how to solve it. I also tried changing the checkoutSessionRef to:

```
checkoutSessionRef = await addDoc(
  collection(db,"users", uid, "checkout_sessions"),
  {
    price: "price_1ODfHmDueGWaYjB35b45Vl1B",
    success_url: window.location.origin + "/settings",
    cancel_url: window.location.origin + "/for-you",
  }
);
```

[this is an image of the error I get in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUclo.png)

Comment: It seems like your `addDoc` function doesn't seem to like the arguments you're passing into it. You'd likely want to check the extension as well as just firebase documentation to verify what sort of structure/datatypes does the function expect.

Comment: Check the docs for [addDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) and look closely at the parameters passed. You should not use `doc()` at all. Your second code example looks more correct but it doesn't match the error screenshot so it's not clear if you actually tried it

Comment: @Haroon The code you have provided would likely not be the issue as this would be caused by the value of `firestore`, `db` and/or `uid`. Based on the error message you see, I'm going to say that it is most likely that your `uid` variable is a number or an object instead of a string. Please add the code where `createMonthlyCheckout` is called along with the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify({ uid, uidType: typeof uid }))`. Depending on what you find, you may be able to use `""+uid` to force the conversion to a string.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience working with Firebase, running into errors like you are seeing can be resolved rapidly (or avoided entirely) if you break your code into ***one-statement-does-one-thing***

Instead of:

```js
 checkoutSessionRef = await addDoc(
      collection(doc(firestore, "users", uid), "checkout_sessions"),
      {
        price: "price_1ODfHmDueGWaYjB35b45Vl1B",
        success_url: window.location.origin + "/settings",
        cancel_url: window.location.origin + "/for-you",
      }
    );
```

I would write it as:

```js
 console.log("firestore is:", firestore);

 let collRef = collection(firestore, "users", uid, "checkout_sessions");
 console.log("collRef path:", collRef.path);

 let data = {
        price: "price_1ODfHmDueGWaYjB35b45Vl1B",
        success_url: window.location.origin + "/settings",
        cancel_url: window.location.origin + "/for-you",
 };
 console.log("data is:", data);

 checkoutSessionRef = await addDoc(collRef, data);
```

Note that if `data` has any values that are `undefined` then you will get errors.  Also you likely want to validate that your `firestore` value is valid.

I also don't like to call `getFirestore()` multiple times.  I prefer to call `initializeApp()` and get handles to all the needed services at the start of my program, then pass those values to other parts of my code where needed.  If this is React (it seems to be from the stack trace) you might pass values around using the Context API or some type of state management library.

See the `FirebaseProvider.jsx` and the `AuthProvider.jsx` at [this "React starter project"](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore).